# Are all Gods and Goddesses omnipresent?

Tags: gods, vedanta, dharma, dharma-shastras, devi

NOTE: I am not just talking about Krishna, but all Devatās. Most answers here tend to be Vaishnava-centric, and only cite examples involving Krishna or Vishnu.

Comment: There are only 33 koti(category) gods and Vishnu, an Aditya, is one of them, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-three_gods, and are Omnipresent i.e. Brahman projects Maya with predefined 33 gods. "They call him Indra, Mitra, Varuna, Agni, and he is heavenly-winged Garutman. To what is One, sages give many a title." — Rigveda 1.164.46"

Comment: All the Gods and Goddesses are the manifestations of one Supreme Brahman, that Brahman itself is all that is.  That's another question though, the level and extent of the manifestation of the Brahman in its Saguna form, and the hierarchy of all those manifestations , which is generally defined by the puranas concerning different sects (पुराण)

Comment: To avoid any controversy, anything that has been called as Brahman, **might** be considered Omnipresent.

Comment: Well, if all the gods are just Brahman, and Brahman is said to be omnipresent entity, then by that logic we could say all the gods are omnipresent. But if they are all omnipresent, then who is not omnipresent? Is there anyone who is not omnipresent, then?